# How to delete Entire Column in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to remove empty columns in excel and please look into below code and suggest corrections.

```
Sub RemoveEmptyCol()
Dim lc As Double
lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To lc
If Cells(1, i).Value = "" Then
Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I tried above code to remove empty column but it didn't removed all empty columns in single run.

Comment: You need to loop backwards `For i = lc To 1 step-1`

Comment: @ScottCraner - could you please tell me in detail. I'm not getting you point.

Comment: replace this `For i = 1 To lc` with `For i = lc To 1 step-1`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Thank you very much... It's working...

Comment: @ScottCraner - I'm not getting idea for 5% sampling for QC on users production. Could you please tell me your mail id. I'll send full details to you and please support me to write code for that task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Craner is on point with the looping backward, and I will add another valuable piece of information that will assist in processing time, especially if you have many, many rows of data, as deleting entire columns can be resource heavy.

The below code will remove the blank columns for only rows where the actual data is stored. It assumes column A has the entire row set fill in. If not, adjust based on whatever column does.

```
Sub RemoveEmptyCol()

    Dim lc As Long, lr as Long
    lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lc To 1 Step -1

        If Cells(1, i).Value = "" Then 

            Range(Cells(1, i),Cells(lr,i).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: And what happens when the data in column A is less then other columns? 8P

Comment: good point brother @ScottCraner, I forgot to mention that assumption ;)